# C# Get Windows User Display Name Error with UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, string

I've been trying to get the display name of a user for an app I'm building. I worked on the **accountmanagement.dll** in my project and I'm using this code to grab the name:

```cs
string userFullName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
```

The following error messages comes up in debug:

> Unable to cast object of type
>
> 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal'

I'm obviously missing something but not sure about the next step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, I have the using in the beginning.   - web config auth is set to   <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>     if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get the windows logged in user name when developing a web app:

```
string userFullName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

and web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: thanks - i will give this a try. I'm also pulling in the username and storing in a sql db so hopefully the windows mode will still work.